Slicing and gluing topological objects : a Klein bottle circle dance
Consider this Klein bottle model

Slicing the model with a horizontal plane from top to bottom gives this beautiful circle dance (also reminiscent of this MRI scan). Hurray!

As far as I know, this is the first time I see a klein bottle presented "programatically" as such (i.e. a circle splits into two lengthwise, then one circle moves outside the other, only to later collide and merge).
Are there other notable examples of this kind of slice construction of topological objects?

This answer presents a similar situation connected to Hopf fibration.

Well, a Klein bottle is a surface, so it's 2D. But sure, you can't embed it in 3D Euclidean space without self-intersection.

https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1UMtOwzAQvOcrVuIQp3VDW1CFKnLlgpAqxD0yrtOYOlnLj9D269ngABJSfbBmZ2bHu76BZ6N0D%2D8YglEl7F5g%5Far7QzYIx%5FLIh7zIsr1q4DjaWLHNgI6DCtawAImexeKbOhF1B7OJIsBWMAdPPbFIjjM5HAkjNyTqQtTiYeKmIN1AhEewOj2Vsuep9Td8BFNGypn%5FZf83KOPVlazJ4VSIrocThzOHS9pXNixyGIrtjxrhFhqDIrD1zOrxV7Cj8ZccxjrbEbbCiU4Fp2VtDQY2%5FRkHsk7XyNcWdR98xe6pebUhvVO%2Drd5cVJzmkWjQVUw2PMFOWF%2D2fqgdOWnBg1G113uVGgCtkDqcq2W5KbJd6Vv8ZM04R%5FUkaHMOoVVU5HvhjjkN4PBDyaCxr3J0ocWDE7bVkiTsje5TbJF9AQ0KmBw=&lang=sage

This is an elementary example illustrating the Morse theory.

The Klein bottle embeds in $\mathbb{R}^4$, and you can imagine 3D slices rather than these 2D slices. In that case, you could have one of the two circles pass under the other; in 4D you don't need the self-intersection. This is a way people study (knotted) surfaces in 4D, with sequences of births, deaths, and saddle moves. This comes from Morse theory.

Thank you for the metnion of Morse Theory, I was not aware of it
